# Counterexample to a set with a unquie maximal element implying existence of a largest element

Tags: order-theory

In Willard's *General Topology*, he defines a maximal element to be an element of a set $A$ provided $(\forall b \in A) \ \ b_1 \leq b \implies b_1=b $. He provides this afterwards:
[image]

I don't see how $b$ is a maximal element. For instance, we have $b \leq a_6$, which certainly doesn't imply $b = a_6$. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, $b\not\le a_6.$ The diagram shows $b$ being incomparable with $a_5,a_6,a_7,\dots.$

Comment: Ohhh okay, I wanted to assume that at first but wasn't positive. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: For a concrete example, let the ordering be divisibility of integers, so that $x\le y$ means $x$ divides $yl$ and let $a_n=2^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and $b=48.$

Comment: Ahh, that clears up the concept of elements being incomparable. Thank you again :)